# how to remove lighting in ursina?

Tags: lighting, ursina

I am making a game and I want to implement a sun rise and sun set.
I tried to find an answer in the 'ursina cheat sheet' but I could not find an answer there.
more specifically I want to remove the lighting that you get when you make a ursina game.

Thanks

Comment: There's no lighting by default.

Answer (score 1):

Easy to do:

```
Dl = DirectionalLight()
Dl.disable() # disables the Directional light
```